# Jquery folding effect website

Tags: jquery, html, effect

I found a website today and i really liked the folding effect
http://www.forsorenda.dk/
when you click "luk op" the page is folding out like a Brochure
anyone have any idea to the jquery code to this im totally lost in thi situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is theme Called
BookCard - Responsive 3D Folded vCard

Reference:[**BookCard**](http://themeforest.net/item/bookcard-responsive-3d-folded-vcard/4285225)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my code: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/4wrnf/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="brochure">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="center"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -200px 0 0 -100px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

#brochure {
    position: relative;
}

#brochure div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}

#left {
    background: red;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
}

#center {
    background: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}

#right {
    background: green;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}

#left, #right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
}

#brochure:hover #left {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}

#brochure:hover #right {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

It works in webkit browsers. If you need support for more, just add more prefixed properties.